# In what condition, the universal covering group of some matrix Lie group is still a matrix Lie group.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

As we know the universal covering group of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group which cannot be faithfully represented by a finite dimensional matrix.

For example,
for  $N>2$, the (double) [covering group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group) of the general linear group is the [metalinear group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metalinear+group) $ML(N,\mathbb{R})$. The metalinear group is a subgroup of the [metaplectic group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metaplectic+group) $Mp(2N,\mathbb{R})$ in twice the dimension.

Therefore what's the sufficient and necessary condition in which the universal covering group of some matrix Lie group is still a matrix Lie group?